# How to optimize a view of a document with thousands of nodes without changing business logic?

Tags: angularjs

I have performance problems with a legacy angular 1.2.30 application. Its main component is a directive that calls itself recursively to display nodes of a tree.

The tree has grown over time and how has thousands of nodes. Since the tree is so big, there's no need to display it completely. Users will be happy to have a moving window into the tree. This looks like a very common problem, but I struggle to find a common solution.

I'd rather avoir modifying the tricky buisness logic, though. Is there any way to display part of the model only?

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar scenario for displaying a navigation tree. Rendering of the child nodes is handled using a recursive template and `ng-if`. The tree is rendered with all nodes collapsed and only the root nodes displayed by default. Child nodes are only rendered when the parent is expanded.

The basic code looks like this:

```
<ul class="tree-list">
    <li ng-repeat="child in rootList" ng-include="'navigation_tree.html'" ng-class="{ 'treeOpen': child.Open && child.Children.length > 0, 'treeClose': !child.Open && child.Children.length > 0 }"></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="navigation_tree.html">
    <span class="tree-icon">
        <a ng-click="child.EnableDetails = true; child.Open = !child.Open;">
            <img ng-src="arrow.png" />
        </a>
    </span>
    <span>{{child.DisplayName}}</span>
    <ul ng-if="child.EnableDetails">
        <li ng-repeat="child in child.Children" ng-include="'navigation_tree.html'" ng-class="{ 'treeOpen': child.Open && child.Children.length > 0, 'treeClose': !child.Open && child.Children.length > 0 }"></li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

The first part of the magic is this line in the template:

```
<ul ng-if="child.EnableDetails">
```

The `EnableDetails` property defaults to `undefined`, which is falsey, so the child nodes do not get rendered by Angular until that property is set to `true`.

The second part of the magic is in the `ng-click` handler that expands the node:

```
<a ng-click="child.EnableDetails = true; child.Open = !child.Open; ">
```

Note that it first sets the `EnableDetails` property to `true`, then toggles the open/expanded state. So the first click on a node will set the property to allow its children to be rendered in addition to setting its expanded state.